# IE and Firefox ignores max-width style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I have those lines:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width:70px">Serial Number</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:DeviceSerialNumber" required />
     </div>
</div>
```

As You can see I want to override bootstraps default max-width of `input-group-addon`.
In chrome it's working and this addon is only 70px wide. But not in FF and IE.

Can You tell me why it's working only in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-width` only works in relationship to the `width` set for the same element, as such- unless you have explicitly set `width`, `max-width` cannot calculate so remains undefined.

[More from MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

> The max-width CSS property is used to set the maximum width of a given
>   element. It prevents the **used value** of the width property from
>   becoming larger than the value specified for max-width.

Comment: There is width set in bootstrap --> for input-group-addon the width is set to 1%. But its way to much for me so I want to lock it at max-width. Style above works in Chrome In ie and ff don't

Comment: @szpic - try also adding `display:inline-block`

Comment: Thanks for guidance. I set min width to 0 and now firefox  foesnt ignore my max width

Comment: @szpic - great, glad you found your solution :)